# Is there a difference between "is" and isKindOfClass()?

Tags: swift

Swift provides the `is` keyword (and `as?`) to check whether an object can be downcast successfully:

```
if foo is MyClass {
    // ...
}
```

But `NSObjectProtocol` also provides the original `func isKindOfClass(aClass: AnyClass!) -> Bool`:

```
if something.isKindOfClass(MyClass) {
    // ...
}
```

For classes conforming to `NSObjectProtocol`, is this really much different?

Comment: I think the main difference is `as?`/`is` works for object/struct that not conforming to `NSObjectProtocol`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Yes** there is a difference: `is` works with any class in Swift, whereas `isKindOfClass()` works only with those classes that are subclasses of `NSObject` or otherwise implement `NSObjectProtocol`.

Comment: I think OP is really asking about `is` instead of `as?`

Comment: Doh -- the question originally specified `as?`, but seems to have been edited. I'll fix up my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the sudden edit — I realized that `is` is closer to `isKindOfClass` than `as?` :)

Comment: No worries -- I (inadvertently) pretty much stole @BryanChen's comment for use in my answer. Sorry, Bryan! I'll mark this Community Wiki just to be fair.

Comment: "whereas isKindOfClass() works only with those classes that are subclasses of NSObject or otherwise implement NSObjectProtocol." It also works on native Swift classes, if you cast it to `AnyObject`: `(something as AnyObject).isKindOfClass(MyClass)`

Answer (score 20):

Some differences:

- `is` works on non-class types. `isKindOfClass:` only works on objects to check whether they are an instance of a class
- As already mentioned by others, `isKindOfClass:` is declared on `NSObjectProtocol`, so it won't let you use it on expressions that are not known to be in that protocol, except `AnyObject`. Actually, native Swift classes also (unofficially) conform to `NSObjectProtocol`, so if you cast them to `AnyObject`, you can still use `isKindOfClass`: `(something as AnyObject).isKindOfClass(MyClass)`
- `is` also works to check against protocols, whereas the equivalent in terms of `NSObjectProtocol` methods would be `conformsToProtocol:`
- `is` takes a type that must be hard-coded at compile-time. `isKindOfClass:` takes an expression whose value can be computed at runtime. I don't know of a way to check whether an object is an instance of a class (including subclasses) that is computed at runtime using just the Swift standard library.

Answer (score 9):

In Objective-C, you use the `isKindOfClass:` method to check whether an object is of a certain class type, and the `conformsToProtocol:` method to check whether an object conforms to a specified protocol. In Swift, you accomplish this task by using the `is` operator to check for a type, or the `as?` operator to downcast to that type.

You can check whether an instance is of a certain subclass type by using the `is` operator. The `is` operator returns `true` if the instance is of that subclass type, and `false` if it is not.

SWIFT

```
if object is UIButton {
    // object is of type UIButton
} else {
    // object is not of type UIButton
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html