# "is" keyword in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

As far as I can look, it seems that the consensus is that the `is` in Swift keyword is synonymous to `isKindOfClass` method.

However, I'm having trouble getting the following to work:

```
//inside of a method in UITabViewController

//check if the currently selected tab is ActivityViewController
if selectedViewController is ActivityViewController {
    print("isActivity")
} else {
    print("isNotActivity")
}


//same check
if selectedViewController?.isKindOfClass(ActivityViewController) != nil {
    print("isActivity")
} else {
    print("isNotActivity)
}
```

When this block of code was called, I made sure I was in my `ActivityViewController` tab. `isKindOfClass` was correct, `selectedViewController is ActivityViewController` was not. Any ideas as to why this is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`is` and  `isKindOfClass` are not synonyms, see for example
[Is there a difference between "is" and isKindOfClass()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877661/is-there-a-difference-between-is-and-iskindofclass).

In your case however, the problem is the *optional chaining*.

```
selectedViewController?.isKindOfClass(ActivityViewController)
```

returns an `Optional<Bool>` which is `nil` if the call could *not* be
made (because `selectedViewController` is `nil`), and a non-`nil`
value otherwise. So

```
selectedViewController?.isKindOfClass(ActivityViewController) != nil
```

is true *if* the call could be made, independent of whether the
return value is `true` or `false`.

With

```
if selectedViewController?.isKindOfClass(ActivityViewController) == true { ... }
```

you would get the expected result.

Comment: Your answer is logically sound, but for some reason I'm not getting the right results. `if selectedViewController?.isKindOfClass(ActivityViewController) != true { ... } `  will always be true, regardless of what tab I am in. Testing further...

Comment: @KelvinLau: Note that I suggested to test `== true`. The test `!= true` will hold if either selectedViewController is nil *or* if isKindOfClass return false..

Comment: still not getting different results :(

Comment: So you have a case where the test `if selectedViewController is ActivityViewController` succeeds, but the test `if selectedViewController?.isKindOfClass(ActivityViewController) == true` does not succeed?

Comment: Sorry Martin, the issue was because I had a UINavi in front of ActivityVC

Comment: @KelvinLau: No problem, I'm glad that you figured it out.