# How do I perform either a push UIViewController or a present of UIAlertController?

Tags: swift, mvvm, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller, rx-swift

After some API calls, I have a check to either navigate to another screen or show an alert on the same screen. Currently, I am doing this by creating an observable that returns a **UIViewController** type but pushing a UIAlertController causes problem.

Any suggestions/ideas on how this should be done?

**ViewModel.swift**

```
let nextAction = Observable.combineLatest(appVersionOutput, serviceAvailabilityOutput, getLanguagePackOutput,
                                              resultSelector:
        { appVersion, _, _ -> UIViewController in
            if appVersion.currentAppVersion == "1.0.0" {
                let appServiceAvailability = Availability.shared.getAppStatus()
                if appServiceAvailability {
                    return LoginLandingViewController()
                } else {
                    return ServiceMaintenanceViewController()
                }
            } else {
                return UIAlertController()
            }
        })
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
viewModel.output.nextAction
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] screen in
            self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(screen, animated: true) 
        }) // PROBLEM FACED: Pushing a UIAlertController
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: From my understanding better to return Error, and on the base of Error status show viewcontroller or alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the class using **classForCoder**

```
viewModel.output.nextAction
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] screen in
        if String(describing: screen.classForCoder) == "UIAlertController" {
            //present
            self?.present(screen, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            //navigate
            self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(screen, animated: true)
        } 
    }) // PROBLEM FACED: Pushing a UIAlertController
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

There’re a few options.

The first option is the adoption of your current implementation.
You could pass an information in addition to ViewController in onNext event of nextAction observable, that will tell how to show the VC.

For instance, you can create an associated enum

```
// you can call it NextAction, Action etc
enum PresentationType {
    case
    push(UIViewController),
    present(UIViewController)
}
```

and reuse it like this:

```
let nextAction = Observable.combineLatest(appVersionOutput, serviceAvailabilityOutput, getLanguagePackOutput,
                                          resultSelector:
    { appVersion, _, _ -> PresentationType in
        if appVersion.currentAppVersion == "1.0.0" {
            let appServiceAvailability = Availability.shared.getAppStatus()
            if appServiceAvailability {
                return .push(LoginLandingViewController())
            } else {
                return .push(ServiceMaintenanceViewController()) // use .present if should present modally
            }
        } else {
            return .present(UIAlertController())
        }
})

// somewhere in viewController

viewModel.output.nextAction
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] action in
        switch action {
            case .push(let vc):
                self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            case .present(let vc):
                self?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

The second (and more flexible and testable in some sense) option would be to create a separate Router class which is responsible for creating and showing next screens (with functions `showLogin`, `showAlert` etc). The router can be directly injected in ViewModel and you can call the Router to show next screens in, for example, do(onNext) events in your observables.

Comment: For the Router class approach, do you have any recommended links to read?

Comment: I don’t have specific articles at hands (I believe you can find by searching for RxSwift + Navigation), but have examples of some view models with navigation:

1. CleanArchitecture RxSwift repository, they call it Navigator instead of routers - https://github.com/sergdort/CleanArchitectureRxSwift/blob/master/CleanArchitectureRxSwift/Scenes/AllPosts/PostsViewModel.swift 

2. RxSwift Examples - they call it Wireframe -
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Examples/GitHubSignup/UsingVanillaObservables/GithubSignupViewModel1.swift

Comment: Thank you for the links. Highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the `is` keyword which allows you to check the object type. [More on is keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829697/is-keyword-in-swift). An alternative will be to use `type(of: object)` and compare to `UIAlertViewController.self`

Since you have to present a `UIAlertViewController` and not push it, use if and else with the above to present if type is `UIAlertViewController` and push if otherwise. NB: Unnecessary to check for UIViewController since they all are.