# Array of objects that have specific type

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of object, eg

```
var objects: [AnimalDetailModel] = ...
```

and also three classes

- `AnimalDetailModel` is a base class
- `DogDetailModel` is a class that extends `AnimalDetailModel`
- `CatDetailModel` is a class that extends `AnimalDetailModel`

From a `datasource` I create and add arrays of `DogDetailModel`s, `CatDetailModel`s and `AnimalDetailModel`s to `objects`. And when populating the tableView what I want is to get an object form objects and check if it is of type `DogDetailModel`, `CatDetailModel` or `AnimalDetailModel` like

```
if let objects[indexPath.row] as? DogDetailModel {    
    return DogTableCell    
} else if let objects[indexPath.row] as? CatDetailModel {    
    return CatTableCell     
} else {    
    return AnimalTableCell    
}
```

While doing this I get type `AnimalDetailModel` has no subscript members. How do we check the type of objects from array of objects?

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile. You need something like `if let someVariable = objects[....`

Comment: As you found the answer to the question yourself or if you choose any of the other answers correct. Please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the short and simple `is` attribute.

which in your case will be:

```
switch objects[indexPath.row] {
    case is DogDetailModel:
        return DogTableCell
    case is CatDetailModel:
        return CatTableCell
    default:
        return AnimalTableCell
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to assign the cast to a variable in your if/else but since you are not using the result of the cast you can use _

```
if let _ = objects[indexPath.row] as? DogDetailModel {    
    return DogTableCell    
} else if let _ = objects[indexPath.row] as? CatDetailModel {    
    return CatTableCell     
} else {    
    return AnimalTableCell    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For your Specific case @Vollan's answer is good. However you would want to show other things like a comment liked or disliked or a user blocked by other user or rank of users  etc... To show such different cases on UITableViewCells or UICollectionViewCells my approach is first define an enum

```
enum modelIdentifier: String {
    case dogDetailModel =  "dogDetailModel"
    case catDetailModel = "catDetailModel"
    case animalDetailModel = "animalDetailModel"
}
```

then pass identifiers into models:

```
struct DogDetailModel {
   // var yourJSONobjects : String?  .....
    //add your identifier under your model
    var modelIdentity: modelIdentifier = .dogDetailModel
}

struct CatDerailModel {
    // var yourJSONobjects : String?  .....
    //add your identifier under your model
    var modelIdentity: modelIdentifier = .catDetailModel
}
```

and check it wherever you want:

```
if objects[indexPath.row].modelIdentity ==  .dogDetailModel {
    return DogTableCell
} else if objects[indexPath.row].modelIdentity ==  .catDetailModel {
    return CatTableCell
} else {
    return AnimalTableCell
}
```

Comment: You don't really need the enum to extend string, unless the struct extends codable and the back-end response is "dogDetailModel". Else it will only increase the risk of human errors. `objects[indexPath.row].modelIdentity ==  .dogDetailModel` would be much better. Edit: Also the enum needs to be Codable in that case as well

Comment: What @Vollan said. Also consider a protocol `protocol IdentifiableModel { var modelIdentity: ModelIdentifier { get } }` Then you can extend any type to conform to it.

Answer (score 1):

The operator to check the instance of the variable is "is" and I solved my issue as below

```
if let objects[indexPath.row] is DogDetailModel {    
    return DogTableCell    
} else if let objects[indexPath.row] is CatDetailModel {    
    return CatTableCell     
} else {    
    return AnimalTableCell    
}
```

Comment: Good that you figured it out yourself. However, when writing your own answer to the question. Write it as you have it in a correct format as the code above wont run,

Comment: What have you got the `let`s in there for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the swift standard library function called `isKind(of: AnyClass)`.
For more details please refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol/1418511-iskind)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24877746/4757272 should be careful of using `isKind(of: AnyClass)` when writing in swift